# Do dolls in Rozen Maiden live like a human?

Tags: rozen-maiden

A question about how the *Rozen Maiden* dolls themselves function.  You often see them eat and drink as well as breathe.  Are these functions required for them to continue to exist?   If not, all of those flower burgers and tea was a real waste.  If so or not, what happens to all the waste from the consumed food and liquids?

Simply stating magic is like a cop out, and not thinking about this would seem to be lazy writing. Shinku did not know what a restroom was and at times, there were 7 beings (5 dolls and 2 humans) in that house and never mention them waiting to use the restrooms for a doll's sake.

Of course, this opens up the question about sweating and required bathing and such if they do.  They act like little humans, but they are shown to be porcelain dolls with strings holding them together.  Just doesn't add up. Thoughts?

Comment: It's a show with talking, walking otherwise-literal dolls with spirit/fairy companions powered by MacGuffins who jump between surreal dimensions while being goaded by a man-bunny named Laplace's Demon. In what way is "it's magic" a cop out?  That's how you explain literally everything.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Anime, they're physically porcelain dolls, that are animated using an artificial spirit called a Rozen Mystica. Which is a part of the spirit of their creator that was separated from him, and then divided equally among the dolls.

The Rosa Mystica allows the dolls to move, and to imitate the functions of a living creature, but it doesn't make them actually alive in a biological sense.

For example, they are able to eat and drink, but they don't need food or drink to survive. The only thing that they need to survive is for their key to be wound up occasionally. As is shown when Shinku's keyhole is blocked by one of Suigintou's feathers.

Even though they can move, they're still dolls. They have ball joints under their clothes, and if one of their joints is damaged their limbs come off and can be restored simply by reattaching them.

When they sweat or get out of breath, it's because they were created using part of Rosen's spirit, and it remembers these things and imitates these aspects to make them seem more lifelike.

Answer (score 0):

Well they are technically dolls and they have an artificial heart. So maybe they are set to behave like normal humans but since they are dolls, they cannot sweat or excrete. I think the artificial heart (or the source of their power and the reason they can move {I forgot what it was called -_-}) destroys or burns the food they eat.

[This is just my theory]